# SSIS ODBC Destination cannot recognize correct column name

Tags: ssis

I'm using MySQL 8.0. I have a table rpt_ua_valuation which has charset utf8mb4, collation utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci. When I add an ODBC Destination in Data Flow of SSIS package. There is an error as below

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0207015
Error at Data Flow Task [ODBC Destination [165]]: There is more than one data source column with the name "Pol???????????s".  The data source column names must be unique.
```

Do you know why it cannot recognize the columns with correct name? Are there any workarounds?
I'm creating SSIS package in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9.15, the SSIS version 15.0.1301.433

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the root cause. It is because I'm using MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver for ODBC Destination.
It works well after changing to MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver.